# How can I add shortcut to VS2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, shortcut

How can I add `Ctrl+D` for **duplicate line** in Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: [Identifying and Customizing Keyboard Shortcuts in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zwses53(v=vs.130).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the following C# command with my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension and assign the <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> shortcut to it in keyboard options:

```
public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
{
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.Copy");
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.Paste");
}
```